# How to clip an image with jQuery without a plugin

Tags: jquery, image-clipping

How do I clip an image in jQuery without a plugin?  I want to create a 360 image rotator by placing all of the images in a single image and then have jQuery navigate to the correct X,Y coordinates in that master image and display the correct clip of the image in a `div`.

Comment: Why not take advantage of the freely available work others have already done? Is there something about a plugin that bothers you?

Comment: I can't find a plugin that doesn't have the GPL attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the large image as the background of your fixed-size div through CSS and then use jQuery to manipulate the background-position values.